# Why do large amounts of libcurl connections lock up my windows system?

Tags: c++, c, windows, network-programming, libcurl

I've made a simple app that creates a libcurl object and starts sending http messages.  I point them at another box on my local network running netcat as a server.  I start up 200 of these on my windows machine.  The netcat server responds to many of the requests, though so many are going on that it misses a majority of them due to timeout.

You can find full source [here](https://github.com/tomisarobot/curl_race), with the actual code being [here](https://github.com/tomisarobot/curl_race/blob/master/source/main_curl_race.cpp).  If you poke around in there you can see how I build and run the test app.

Within a few minutes the system will become unresponsive.  I am forced to hit the power button to get access again.  It does not respond to telnet, remote debugging, RDP, though it will respond to pings.  It does not create a crash dump.

The real problem here is that I don't understand how to catch this while its happening, so I don't know how to debug it.  I'm hoping someone knows the correct way to diagnose this.

I can probably avoid this by implementing some QoS type behavior.  Unless I can measure what is actually locking up the system, I'm afraid that I'll just be masking the issue.

If you start the processes with /BELOWNORMAL it seems to reproduce much faster.

I was unable to reproduce this on the same machine when in safe mode.  I was unable to reproduce this on my mac.  I've disabled AV/Firewall, no difference.  I've checked my drivers, which seem to be up to date.  I've made it happen on multiple machines with different hardware configurations.

I've monitored all the metrics I know to check, cpu, ram, NPP, ports, handles, threads, nothing seems alarming.  I've started up 600 with not much difference, so I don't think I'm hitting some hard resource limit.

I've asked the libcurl mailing list and they claim that libcurl shouldn't be able to do this, though they had no input on what the problem was.

Comment: How about firing up a performance profile like [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) and see where it takes which amount of time?

Comment: @UweKeim I'm not using .NET, just plain C++.  Is that still appropriate?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I used performance profilers "back then" (C++), too, but I do not recall which ones.

Comment: You can also make a log file, write down meaningful events and timestamps, then do some analysis when the machine comes back up.

Comment: @john.pavan I have, though it seemed fairly spurious.  I could not find a pattern.

Comment: What (exact) version of Windows? (e.g., "Windows 7 Ultimate"). System is "unresponsive". Can you start Task Manager before this and then still interact with Task Manager when it happens?

Comment: You're likely getting close to some artificial upper limit in the OS for number of threads or number of simultaneous connections. Or perhaps a virus scanner is monitoring each connection and that is slowing your system?

Comment: @RonBurk I'm on Win7 enterprise.  I cannot interact with it after this happens.  None of the stats indicate any change either.  The onset is rather sudden, so I would not assume that it is getting that last update in.

Comment: @cppguy My non-toy application has 3 more threads per app and still runs for a while with 600, so I don't think its threads.  The connection has to be flaky, so connections is somewhat plausible.  I watched the connections listed in netstat and that was not ballooning.  Is there another method you could recommend?

Comment: Just for grins, can you see if there's a HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\MaxUserPort and, if so, what its value is? TCP port exhaustion (artificial or not) shouldn't lock up the machine, but...  All disks have plenty of space and no errors? You've checked the event log? Run chkdsk?

Comment: @RonBurk I don't have `MaxUserPort` set, and I checked that it wasn't growing via netstat and didn't see any weird growth.  Event log is empty, disk has space, haven't run chkdsk, though I've reproduced it on two separate machines which makes me think its software.